# 4 + 1 stacked monitor setup with Synergy

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, linux-mint, synergy

Is it possible to configure synergy to accommodate the following setup?

```
         +---------------+ +---------------+                                                     
         |    Client     | |    SERVER     |
         |   Display 1   | |   Display 4   |          
         | (Mint Linux)  | |    (Win7)     |
         +---------------+ +---------------+
+---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+
|    SERVER     | |    SERVER     | |    SERVER     |
|   Display 1   | |   Display 2   | |   Display 3   |                      
|    (Win7)     | |    (Win7)     | |    (Win7)     |
+---------------+ +---------------+ +---------------+
```

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing.

Unfortunately it appears that the monitors must be organised in a grid, I can't find any way to organise them in an ad-hoc way like you can with monitors in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a way to do this with Synergy 1.3.8 and so if you:
1) Install Synergy 1.3.8 first
2) Set up your monitors the way you like
3) Create your configuration file and save it (synergy.sgc)
4) Uninstall Synergy 1.3.8
5) Install your version of Synergy
6) Tell your new version to use the old configuration file